# Cocos2D: Player controller algorithm glitches when jumping

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm having some trouble with an algorithm for a player controller I'm writing. I'm using Cocos2D to make a platformer style game (think Super Mario Bros.). My controller has a left and right button, and you touch the right half of the screen to jump.

The problem I'm having is when you're holding the right or left button, then hold the screen to jump and let go of the directional button, the player will continue to go in that direction  until the user lifts their finger off the screen.

The other problem is if the user holds the screen to jump, taps a directional button then lets go of the directional while still holding the screen, the player will continue in that direction. Half the time the player stops on release of the screen, the other half the player will continue going on release until the screen is tapped again.

This is my code to register which part of the controller are tapped:

```
- (void) ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for (UITouch* touch in touches)
    {
        CGPoint point = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace: touch];

        // Create a rect around right half of the window
        CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
        CGRect jumpBox = CGRectMake(winSize.width / 2,
                                    0,
                                    winSize.width / 2,
                                    winSize.height);


        // left button
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(leftButtonSprite.boundingBox, point))
        {
            self.isPressingLeftButton = YES;
            self.isPressingRightButton = NO;
        }

        // right button
        else if (CGRectContainsPoint(rightButtonSprite.boundingBox, point))
        {
            self.isPressingRightButton = YES;
            self.isPressingLeftButton = NO;
        }

        // player's trying to jump
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(jumpBox, point))
        {
            self.isTouchingScreen = YES;
        }
    }
}

- (void) ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for (UITouch* touch in touches)
    {
        CGPoint point = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace: touch];

        // Create a rect around right half of the window
        CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
        CGRect jumpBox = CGRectMake(winSize.width / 2,
                                    0,
                                    winSize.width / 2,
                                    winSize.height);


        // left button
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(leftButtonSprite.boundingBox, point))
        {
//            CCLOG(@"Pressing left");
            self.isPressingLeftButton = YES;
            self.isPressingRightButton = NO;
        }

        // right button
        else if (CGRectContainsPoint(rightButtonSprite.boundingBox, point))
        {
//            CCLOG(@"Pressing right");
            self.isPressingRightButton = YES;
            self.isPressingLeftButton = NO;
        }

        // player's trying to jump
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(jumpBox, point))
        {
//            CCLOG(@"Jumping");
            self.isTouchingScreen = YES;
        }

    }
}

- (void) ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (self.isTouchingScreen)
    {
        CCLOG(@"Stop jumping");
        self.isTouchingScreen = NO;
    }
    else
    {
        CCLOG(@"Stop moving");
        self.isPressingLeftButton = NO;
        self.isPressingRightButton = NO;
    }
}
```

This code is in my `HUDLayer.m` which is a child in my `GameplayLayer.m`. GameplayLayer uses `update:` to figure out which of the flags from HUDLayer is set and moves the player accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Kind of a n00b mistake. In `ccTouchesEnded:withEvent:`, I had to `convertTouchToNodeSpace` and check if it intersects the rects of the directional buttons or jump half of the screen as done in `ccTouchesBegan:withEvent:`

Hope this helps someone some day. Happy coding :)